# Is double encryption using AES using different key lengths (128 bit and then 256 bit) vulnerable?

Tags: encryption, aes, cryptanalysis, attack, meet-in-the-middle-attack

I know that AES 256 bit is far more than enough to secure a file. I just want to know if there are any vulnerabilities or known attacks which can make such this combination less secure "double encryption using AES using different key lengths (first 128 bit and then 256 bit)".

Say, for example, I have a program that can encrypt a file using AES 128 bit and another program which uses AES 256 bit. Also, I have assumed that **either one** of these encryption programs have a flaw.

Case 1: So, is it possible that if AES 256 bit program fails (because of the *flaw in its implementation* by the programmer), the attacker will only find the file encrypted by the strong AES 128 bit and won't be able to proceed forward?

Can Case 1 be true?

Please note that the keys are not related in any way. I'm not an expert in Cryptography and I'm trying to understand its basics. So, if you may please reply in simple terms, that would be much appreciated. Thank you. :)

Comment: AES-256(AES-128(m)) has 256 bit security. Double encryption *shouldn't* reduce security (at least with symmetric crypto).

Comment: @otus: Hi, i did read it before but it mentions about TLS protocol. I was a bit confused by the terms used there. What is your opinion about the combination mentioned in my question?